# What is the nuance of お人好し vs いい人?

Tags: word-choice, manga

I'm reading the manga 僕だけがいない街 where the following is thought about a character who is kind towards the protagonist:

> 相変わらず｛あいかわらず｝お人好し｛おひとよし｝。。。いやいい人｛ひと｝だ。

The implication is that the guy is a good person. What is the difference though between お人好し and いい人 that the protagonist finds necessary to emphasize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

お人【ひと】好【よ】し usually has a negative connotation; someone who is generous to a fault, someone who doesn't know how to doubt others. 「彼はお人好しだ」 is mildly derogatory in most cases.

いい人 is usually positive (「彼はいい人だ」 is not derogatory), although it may be used sarcastically depending on the context.

In this sentence, the speaker rephrased お人好し as いい人 because the latter sounds much milder and euphemistic, but he probably thinks the person is お人好し.